# Replacing Head of Expression with Table but the variable inside the expression cannot Increment

Tags: list-manipulation

What is wrong and why I cannot get `z = 0; Apply[Table, {z++, {i, 0, 9}}]` to output exactly like `z = 0; Table[z++, {i, 0, 9}]`?

Comment: try `z = 0; Apply[Table, Unevaluated@{z++, {i, 0, 9}}]`?

Comment: To elaborate on @kgir's comment, Mathematica first evaluates `{z++, {i,0,9}}` to `{0, {i, 0, 9}}` and only then applies `Table`.  Unevaluated postpones that evaluation.

Comment: Or just `Table @@ {i, {i, 0, 9}}`

Answer (score 6):

You don't get the same output because when you evaluate `z = 0; Apply[Table, {z++, {i, 0, 9}}]` `z++` evaluates to `0` before the head gets replaced. `Table` has the attribute `HoldAll` which prevents the arguments to be evaluated prematurely.

If you want to maintain some arguments in an unevaluated form, waiting for the correct head to be applied, you should wrap them in `Hold` instead:

```
z = 0; Apply[Table, Hold[z++, {i, 0, 9}]]
(*{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}*)
```

Comment: I upvoted because of the second sentence. This is the critical part.